# Shopify API calls not working in Rails background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, background-process

In my Rails controller action, I have a method that does a bunch of Shopify API calls. Things like:
`ShopifyAPI::Product.all()`

`ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: {title: title})`

`ShopifyAPI::Product.create(title: title, body_html: description, images: images, tags: tags, product_type: product_type)`

All of it does what I want...very neat.

The problem is that I'm going to be uploading a CSV and using this controller method. It's fine if I have like 8 line items, but very quickly it gets slow. So, I thought, let's move it to a background worker.

I'm using Redis/Resque to get everything going and using some dummy outputs (i.e. `puts 'Hi there champ!'`) I've confirmed that the background worker is configured properly and executing when and where it should be. Neat.

So then I put bits and pieces of my controller action in and output that. That all works until I hit my Shopify API calls. I can call `.new` on about any object, but the when I try to `.find`, `.all`, or `.create` any valid object (which worked before I abstracted it to the background job), it sort of goes dead. Super descriptive! I've *tried* to output what's going on via `logger` and `puts` but I can't seem to generate much output of what's going on, but I have isolated it down to the Shopify API work. I thought that, even though I have an initializer that specifies my passwords, site, API keys, secrets, etc, I might need to reinitialize my Shopify session, as per [their setup docs here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api#getting-started). I either did it wrong, or that did solve the issue.

At this point I'm sure I'm just missing something in the docs, but I cannot find out how to make these necessary API calls from my background job. Any thoughts on what I might be doing obviously wrong that could solve this? Anyone dealt with anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this has to do with where the Shopify Engine was mounted. In my `routes.rb` I have the following (in addition to other routes; these are the two pertinent ones):

```
mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/'
root to: 'products#index'
```

This is all fine and good, but sort of forces the context of your Shopify API calls to be made within the context of the `products.rb` index controller action...without some changes. 2 ways to do this, one obviously the more Railsy way to do it:

**Option 1:**

Include

```
session = ShopifyApp::SessionRepository.retrieve(1)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
```

at the beginning of any file in which you want to make Shopify API calls. This sets the session (assuming you only have 1 store, by the way...this is using the retrieve method to retrieve store 1. Risky assumption), authenticate to the API, and everything in life is good.

**Option 2:**

***Class inheritance for the win.*** Have all your controllers that are making API calls inherit from `ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController`. This makes the initializer actually work, and that's it. This is (in retrospect) the clear and obvious way to go. Have an order controller? `class OrdersController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController` and done: `order = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(params[:id])` does exactly what you'd expect it to.